# Configure an OWIN static file server at a specific route prefix

Tags: asp.net, owin, fileserver

I'm experimenting with keeping my content in non-default locations (eg in `bower_components` or `/packages/../tools`). As part of the experiment I am trying to set up an asp.net mvc 5 application where hitting a certain route allows me to browse files in the undersorejs package directory.

I have the following nuget packages (in addition to the default)

```
Install-Package underscore.js
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
```

This is what I have in an OWIN startup class

```
 var fileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(
                    HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~")+"/../packages/underscore.js.1.6.0"
                  );
 var options = new FileServerOptions {EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true, FileSystem = fileSystem};

 app.MapWhen(ctx => 
      ctx.Request.Uri.AbsolutePath.StartsWith("/__underscore"), 
      ab => ab.UseFileServer(options)
 );
```

To my understanding and previous experimentation this is pretty straightforward - when the request begins with `/__underscore` [use the simple static file server](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/02/10/building-a-simple-file-server-with-owin-and-katana.aspx). However when I head over to `/__underscore` I get a 404 error.

However, placing breakpoints I can see that the UseFileServer lambda executes once on startup and then never again, while the predicate lambda is called on every request (and returns the correct value).

What am I missing?

Comment: How is the application hosted?

Comment: @haim770 iis express. Just default MVC asp.net web project and f5 at the moment

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to specify the `RequestPath` as well:

```
var options = new FileServerOptions {
                      EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true,
                      FileSystem = fileSystem,
                      RequestPath = PathString.FromUriComponent("/__underscore")
                      };
```

**As per your comment:**

If you're unable to download files, try to explicitly register `OwinHttpHandler` in your `Web.Config`:

```
<system.webServer> 
    <handlers> 
        <add name="Owin" verb="" path="*" type="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb"/> 
    </handlers> 
</system.webServer>
```

Alternatively, you can set `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` to 'true':

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: aha! so secondary question - why did the handlers run in that order? shouldn't the second lambda run whenever the predicate returns true?

Comment: Interesting, it now allows navigation but results in a 404 when I try to download a file

Comment: What's the file extension?

Comment: Great, that worked! Any insight into why that handler is necessary? I believe Owin is a huge deal and I'd really would like to understand what's going on with this at as deep a level as possible.

Comment: interesting, I added the `handlers` node above and now any requests to the Content and Scripts directories no longer work. Whats going on?!

Comment: If you'll limit `OwinHandler` to the `__underscore` path you'll be fine (`<add name="owin" verb="" path="/__underscore" type="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb"/>`). Yet, i have to admit that it's still unclear to me too how exactly Owin integrates with IIS pipeline (which is what causes the problems here as hosting the app outside of IIS works great).

Comment: Apparently IIS `StaticFileHandler` is taking over such requests, and when no explicit configuration to run other modules (Owin), it (rightly) aborts the request with 404 as no static file is matching `__underscore/.....`.