# Owin OAuth localhost/Token returns 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

Firstly, everything works when I run it from Visual Studio using `iis express`.

I have an Asp.Net Web Api running Owin OAuth. This is the configuration part of my `Startup` class:

```
private static void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var oAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
    #if DEBUG
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    #endif
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider()
    };

    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthOptions);
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
}
```

This is the `Register` part of my `WebApiConfig.cs`

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services
    config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
    config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(cors);

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    // OData
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Employee>("Employee");
    config.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "ODataRoute",
        routePrefix: "odata/",
        model: builder.GetEdmModel()
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I have deployed this application on IIS version 8.5.* and everything works except the `localhost/Token` endpoint. It is a combined MVC + Web Api project.

I am using .NET v4.5 application pool (.NET CLR Version: 4.0) with integrated pipeline mode and `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll` is present in the bin folder.

Why do I get 404 when I make a request to the Token endpoint?

Comment: Did you set `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` to true as in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101432/configure-an-owin-static-file-server-at-a-specific-route-prefix)?

Comment: Yes, it does not work either.

Comment: I will post an update shortly

Comment: found any solution ?...please update us

Comment: try adding     <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />  in web.config

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue. Here is your problem:

```
#if DEBUG
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
#endif
```

Locally (IISExpress), you're running a DEBUG build and your compiler directive sets the `AllowInsecureHttp` to `true`. This means you can ask a new OAuth token over both http and https.

Deploying to IIS means that you first do a RELEASE build. So the compiler directive omits the `AllowInsecureHttp` line. The property defaults to `false`, which means you can only get an OAuth token over http**s**. If you try ask a token over http, the server will answer with a `404`.

Answer (score 0):

install Nuget package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb because your handler are not registering.

if still not work then add the following handler in web.config file

```
  <add name="Owin" verb="" path="*" type="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb"/>


</handlers>
```